# How to Import a CSV file into an entity automatically?

Tags: csv, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Is there a way to import a CSV file into a CRM record automatically, say when the CSV file is created?

The plan is that this CSV file would have some cost center hours inside and job number which corresponds to a certain record already created in CRM. 
And uploading this CSV would then update this record.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: you may want to review [Ask], and research Microsoft Power Automate.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure Power Automate would work, this is all on premise so limits me on the use of cloud services.

Comment: Use File system watcher, Task scheduler, Console app, SSIS, etc by mix & match to achieve the automagic data load :)

Answer (score 0):

You can import data both using UI and code in D365. 
Also there are plenty of tools solving exactly same problem: KingswaySoft SSIS, Scribe, etc.

But it looks like buying 3rd party software might be overkill in your scenario. You can use Windows task scheduler and write a few PowerShell scripts to implement it.

Where to start:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/import-data
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/sample-import-data-complex-data-map
3. https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/define-alternate-keys-entity